# check if embedded FB posts appeared in screen js

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to fetch post from FB ...

```html
<html>
 <title>My Website</title>
  
<head> 
  
</head>
<body>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  
  </script>

  <div class="fb-post" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/"
     data-width="500">
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to execute  some JS function when the embedded post from FB (in class "fb-post") fetch it and it appeared on the screen. 
In another word,

How would I know using JS that the post is fetched from FB and it already appeared on the screen ?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Please see it again, I update it

Comment: in modern browsers can use MutationObserver API, otherwise would need to use interval timer to check for elements